# Are flash loan attacks legal?

Tags: theft, is-x-legal, hacking, cryptocurrency

A new form of "money making activity" has emerged in recent years, the flash loan attack.  In very rough terms, a loan of some cryptocurrency is taken out, the cryptocurrency is used in some currency exchange service that alters the relative value of the two cryptocurrencies, profit is made from this change, and the loan is paid back within the same transaction.  [Further details about one such attack is here](https://peckshield.medium.com/warpfinance-incident-root-cause-analysis-581a4869ee00), with this graphical summary:

[image: graphical summary of flash loan attack]

This is generally referred to as an exploit, attack, hack or theft, but is it illegal?  [Flash loans are intentionally created feature](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-02-07/flash-loans-are-providing-instant-cash-to-crypto-speculators), and utilising changes in the relative value of assets is a common feature of financial markets.  Is any law being broken in these attacks?

As far as jurisdiction is concerned I do not know which matter.  Any would be interesting, as would any details about which jurisdiction would be concerned given the international nature of these services.

Comment: Can you explain further why you characterize this as an "attack"? That might help understand the potential illegality that you see here.

Comment: Whether legal or illegal, victims won't get their money back. To protect yourself from flash loan attacks, stay away from any cryptocurrency.

Comment: @user133469 I call it an attack because that is what the media calls them.  Cf. [Blockworks](https://blockworks.co/avalanche-flash-loan-attack-nets-370k/), [cointelegraph](https://cointelegraph.com/news/defi-protocol-token-nfd-crashes-by-99-after-a-flash-loan-attack), [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/alexandria/article/what-are-flash-loan-attacks).  I suspect it is legal, but only because the laws have not caught up with the tech.

Comment: I believe any answer would have to distinguish between "not-hacks" simply using or creating arbitrage and "hacks" which somehow manipulate the smart contracts. Finding arbitrage opportunities is not generally illegal.

Comment: In the US I believe that the law for this is still being worked out in litigation and legislation. However the SEC has indicated that it thinks many cryptocurrencies qualify as securities. Mixing securities with an activity that includes "price manipulation" sounds like an invitation for criminal charges.

Comment: "the cryptocurrency is used in some currency exchange service that alters the relative value of the two cryptocurrencies" This is the part of the transaction that I don't really understand. Fleshing this out a little more would be helpful. Maybe a concrete example would help.